# Why is traffic not forwarded between LAN and WAN (and vise versa) in my pfSense router?

Tags: networking, routing, pfsense

Below is my configuration

- **VmWare Workstation**

  virtual switch 1 (VMnet1) ;  virtual switch 2 (VMnet2)
- **pfSense Virtual machine**

  interface 1 or le0 (LAN) on VMnet1 ;
  interface 2 or le1 (WAN) on VMnet2
- **Windows 7 client**

  interface 1 or eth0 on VMnet2

eth0 and le1 are on the same network (for instance 192.168.100.0/24) while le0 is on (192.168.200.0/24)

I'd like eth0 to ping le0

Problem 1 : eth0 does not get no reply from le1 since it is a WAN interface ;
Problem 2 : therefore it does not ping le0 (if it does I guess TTL will be decremented)

How do I do that ?

Comment: Does the pfSense firewall have rules allowing the traffic?

Comment: @grawity I did not set anything... It's the default settings.. Let me check if WAN has rules

Comment: WAN and LAN have default rules in pfSense so check these. And make sure that you disabled blocking of private and bogon networks.

Comment: @grawity pffff I've deletes ALL rules in the firewall section...DIsabled EVERYTHING on WAN and LAN....

Comment: So if you've disabled custom ones, you're left with the default-deny rule.

Comment: @grawity hmmm there are not even a single rule in all sections... I just create a rulle with NO restriction on WAN...still nothing... What could I be missing

Comment: In pfSense, the "Firewall" page has custom rules only. pfSense will also load a number of predefined rules, the final one of which drops all unmatched packets.